# systemd httpd stop very slow under Arch Linux

Tags: apache-2.2, arch-linux, systemd

When I perform a:

```
systemctl stop httpd
```

Apache often takes minutes to stop. The command:

```
apachectl gracefully-stop
```

always stops immediately. Anyone have any idea what might be causing this? The commands:

```
systemctl start httpd
```

and

```
apachectl start
```

both run very quickly. Somehow this is both systemd and stopping httpd related (and possibly Arch Linux related).

Answer (score 4):

According to: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=906321 there is an issue with the default systemd KillMode for Apache.

One temporary fix is to add `KillMode=none` to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service`

Be sure to run `sudo systemctl --system daemon-reload` after you make the change.